# Business Logic in MEAN application

Tags: node.js, angular

Should the calculations in an angular application go on the front end or the back end? The application will update the outputs on each input change, is it sensible to fire a request to back end at each input change?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, firing a new request for each input change is expensive. So, it depends on your requirement. If the calculation will be shared among several applications or if it's a proprietary one, you must place it in backend. Otherwise, you can choose to implement the calculation in the frontend.

And do perform a validation in the backend to ensure the correctness of the data sent to the server.

If you choose to make a request for every input change, it is worth to consider **debouncing** your request for better performance.

Comment: thanks, my algorithms do fall under proprietary category. Backend seems to be a sensible place to put them. On the frontend is it a good design to give 2 buttons, one for update (that will let the user change all the inputs and then click update to update the outputs) and save (to save all the updated values in the database)?

Comment: Both update and Save can go in a single button click. No need to have two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the calculations on both sides if the calculations must be performed correctly (like the price calculation on a shopping site).

The backend should perform the calculations after you submit the form to validate that everything is correct.